# How to debug macro annotation in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scala-macros

Debugging normal macros in Intellij works fine as Jan Machacek [explained here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/debugging-scala-macros).

But with a macro annotation I haven't found a way to debug the macro before the process finishes. I tried various settings in Intellij without luck.

Here's a def and annotation macro to debug:

```
package demo
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.Context
import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation

class myAnnotation extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*) = macro Test.transformAnnottees
}

object Test {

  def transformAnnottees(c: Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = {
    println("Annotation macro")  // <-- breakpoint here not reached
    c.Expr[Any](annottees.head.tree) // dummy
  }

  def debug[A]: String = macro Test.debug_impl[A]

  def debug_impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): c.Expr[String] = {
    import c.universe._
    println("Normal macro")  // <-- breakpoint here reached
    c.Expr[String](Literal(Constant(weakTypeOf[A].toString)))
  }
}
```

And a runner:

```
package demo

object TestDebugging extends App {

  @myAnnotation
  class A

  val a = new A

  println(Test.debug[A]) // "demo.TestDebugging.A"
}
```

My Run/Debug configuration in Intellij:

- Type: Application
- Main class: scala.tools.nsc.Main
- VM options: -Dscala.usejavacp=true
- Program arguments: -cp demo.Test mymodule/src/test/scala/demo/TestDebugging.scala
- Working directory: /Users/mg/project/testMacroDebugging
- Environment variables: [none]
- Use class path of module: mymodule
- Before launch: Make

As program arguments I also tried

- -cp demo.myAnnotation mymodule/src/test/scala/demo/TestDebugging.scala

So, I basically said to Intellij that I want to debug `demo.Test` when running `TestDebugging.scala`, right? But when I set a breakpoint in both `transformAnnottees` and `debug_impl` I only get to debug the latter.

I see both "Annotation macro" and "Normal macro" printing during make, so the annotation is apparently working. What am I missing to debug the annotation macro `transformAnnottees`?

(Using Intellij 12.1.6, build 129.1359, JRE 1.6.0_65)

**EDIT:**

As a debugging alternative to having `macroTransform` in the annotation class being called via the annotation, then maybe I could get access to the normal debugging flow if instead called a normal def method

```
def macroTransform2(annottees: Any*): Any = macro transform
```

inside the `Test` object? That would be for just testing purposes and could be commented out when not debugging. I couldn't find a way to supply the equivalent arguments as the annotation sends (the ClassDef)... Is there a way to get this clumsy hack working or better; avoiding it?

Comment: Is the macro paradise plugin added to the classpath of the compiler instance being debugged? If there's no paradise activated, macro annotations won't expand.

Comment: I think so - how can I verify that? I tried debugging your [sbt-example-paradise](https://github.com/scalamacros/sbt-example-paradise). First, I had to add the compiler to the macros project for scala.tools.nsc.Main to be seen in the debugger setup. But it still didn't allow me to step into the macro in a debug session. The process just finishes. Can you verify that you can debug your example with its setup? Thanks for your help and all good macro work!

Comment: To be more precise: I had to add the compiler to the `macros` project to have scala.tools.nsc.Main on the class path of the `core` module in the debugger setup. But I still can't step into `helloMacro` in a debug session.

Comment: Sorry for a very late answer. Could you try adding `-Xplugin:<path to the macro paradise jar> -Xplugin-require:macroparadise` to your program arguments in the debug configuration?